# Read all lines from FileChannel to Stream of strings

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, nio

For my specific task, I need to read the data from `FileChannel` to a `Stream` (or `Collection`) of `String`'s.

In a regular `NIO` for a `Path` we can use a convenient method `Files.lines(...)` which returns a `Stream<String>`. I need to get a same result, but from a `FileChannel` instead of `Path`:

```
public static Stream<String> lines(final FileChannel channel) {
//...
}
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you want the channel to be closed when the returned `Stream` is closed, so the simplest approach would be

```
public static Stream<String> lines(FileChannel channel) {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(channel, "UTF-8"));
    return br.lines().onClose(() -> {
        try { br.close(); }
        catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
    });
}
```

It doesn’t actually require a `FileChannel` as input, a `ReadableByteChannel` is sufficient.

Note that this also belongs to “regular NIO”; `java.nio.file` is sometimes [referred to as “NIO.2”](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html).

Comment: oh darn, you have just corrected a bug in our code base via `onClose`. thank you