# How to read a huge CSV file from Google Cloud Storage line by line using Java?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, nio

I'm new to Google Cloud Platform. I'm trying to read a CSV file present in Google Cloud Storage (non-public bucket accessed via Service Account key) line by line which is around 1GB.

I couldn't find any option to read the file present in the Google Cloud Storage (GCS) line by line. I only see the read by chunksize/byte size options. Since I'm trying to read a CSV, I don't want to use read by chunksize since it may split a record while reading.

**Solutions tried so far:**
Tried copying the contents from CSV file present in GCS to temporary local file and read the temp file by using the below code. The below code is working as expected but I don't want to copy huge file to my local instance. Instead, I want to read line by line from GCS.

```
    StorageOptions options = 
    StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(GCP_PROJECT_ID)
            .setCredentials(gcsConfig.getCredentials()).build();
    Storage storage = options.getService();
    Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME);
    ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
    FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(TEMP_FILE_NAME);
    fileOuputStream.getChannel().transferFrom(readChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    fileOuputStream.close();
```

Please suggest the approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read all lines from FileChannel to Stream of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544945/read-all-lines-from-filechannel-to-stream-of-strings)

Comment: ReadChannel is a subclass of ReadableByteChannel, and you can wrap that in a Reader as the dup shows.

Comment: @DougStevenson I'm reading file inside a batch process. My file would have 10 million records and I don't want to read all the lines at once and crash my JVM

Comment: I understand.  Use the advice in the duplicate. You can arrange to receive the lines individually from a BufferedReader.  You don't have to process them all at once.

Comment: @DougStevenson How to convert a ReadChannel Object to a BufferedReader? Please suggest.

Comment: The dup I linked shows you exactly how to do that.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thats a FileChannel not a ReadChannel

Comment: A FileChannel and ReadChannel share a common superclass ReadableByteChannel, which is the API you're looking for.  It should work the same way.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you! It worked!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since, I'm doing batch processing, I'm using the below code in my ItemReader's init() method which is annotated with @PostConstruct. And In my ItemReader's read(), I'm building a List. Size of list is same as chunk size. In this way I can read lines based on my chunkSize instead of reading all the lines at once.

```
StorageOptions options = 
StorageOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(GCP_PROJECT_ID)
        .setCredentials(gcsConfig.getCredentials()).build();
Storage storage = options.getService();
Blob blob = storage.get(BUCKET_NAME, FILE_NAME);
ReadChannel readChannel = blob.reader();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(Channels.newReader(readChannel, "UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the easiest ways might be to use the `google-cloud-nio` package, part of the google-cloud-java library that you're already using: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/tree/v0.30.0/google-cloud-contrib/google-cloud-nio

It incorporates Google Cloud Storage into Java's NIO, and so once it's up and running, you can refer to GCS resources just like you'd do for a file or URI. For example:

```
Path path = Paths.get(URI.create("gs://bucket/lolcat.csv"));
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
   lines.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
} catch (IOException ex) {
   // do something or re-throw...
}
```

Comment: I saw this approach but my GCS bucket is not public and can be accessed through a service account key. I would get 401 Unauthorized exception if I use the above approach. Can you please suggest alternatives?

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick responses. I don't want to read all the line at once. My file is very huge with 9 million records.

Comment: `Files.readAllLines` reads all the lines at once. `Files.lines()`, in my example, streams through the file instead.

Answer (score 3):

Brandon Yarbrough is right, and to add to his answer:

if you use gcloud to login with your credentials then Brandon's code will work: `google-cloud-nio` will use your login to access the files (and that'll work even if they are not public).

If you prefer to do it all in software, you can use this code to read credentials from a local file and then access your file from Google Cloud:

```java
    String myCredentials = "/path/to/my/key.json";
    CloudStorageFileSystem fs =
        CloudStorageFileSystem.forBucket(
            "bucket",
            CloudStorageConfiguration.DEFAULT,
            StorageOptions.newBuilder()
                .setCredentials(ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(
                    new FileInputStream(myCredentials)))
                .build());
    Path path = fs.getPath("/lolcat.csv");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

edit: you don't want to read all the lines at once so don't use `realAllLines`, but once you have the `Path` you can use any of the other techniques discussed above to read just the part of the file you need: you can read one line at a time or get a `Channel` object.