# Reading large avro files from GCS bucket gives out of memory exception

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, avro, blobstore, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to read large avro file from GCS bucket storage. The file is around 7gb. I'm uisng the below java code to read the file and process.

```
com.google.cloud.storage.Blob blob ; //avro file in GCS 
SeekableByteArrayInput input = new SeekableByteArrayInput(blob.getContent()); //throws memory exception
        DatumReader<GenericRecord> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader();
        DataFileReader<GenericRecord> dataFileReader= new DataFileReader(input, datumReader);
        while (dataFileReader.hasNext()) {
          //logic to process each record in avro file
        }
```

When I'm using blob.getContent(), the program throws out of memory exception. I tried using -Xms -Xmx options to increase memory. But it did not work. What could be better way to load the content of large avro file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55225297/how-to-read-a-huge-csv-file-from-google-cloud-storage-line-by-line-using-java 
Have you seen this? I think this should help you

Comment: DataFileReader accepts input of type SeekableInput. I couldn't find a way to convert the solution in the above link to read avro files..

Comment: This documents [1][2] provides templates to read Cloud Storage Avro to Bigtable and Spanner respectively. This document [3] provide details how to load data from Avro files of GCS to BigQuery table. You can find best practices on how to read large files from GCS here [4]. 

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#avrofiletocloudbigtable
[2] https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#gcsavrotocloudspanner
[3] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-avro 
[4] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IzEP0tKR744

Comment: If you think the issue is technical in nature you can report the issue by creating a Public Issue under Cloud Storage [5]. If you need to share any Project Specific information please select the Private Component. After that one of the Google Cloud Platform Support agent will assist you. [5] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list